# Scrollview скролит вверх только до первого EditText

Tags: android, android-scrollview

У меня на экране для редактирования позиции есть эмуляция диалогового окна(не диалог, потому что некоторые позиции нужно затенять, а некоторые нет). То есть по факту открываю или закрываю ConstraintLayout который расположен по центру экрана. Это диалоговое окно нормально помещается пока не открыли клавиатуру.
В нем есть шапка и ряд полей для ввода, a так же кнопка сохранить.
В дальнейшем оказалось, что на меленьких телефонах кнопка сохранить не помещалась и перекрывалась клавиатурой.
Поэтому решил обернуть ConstraintLayout в ScrollView. В итоге  теперь при открытии клавиатуры содержимое диалогового окна нормально скролится, только вот вехняя шапка съедается(там заголовок и кнопка крестик для закрытия)

Что можно сделать, чтоб при вызове клавиатуры скролилось полноценно все окно? 
Режим активити  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
Если нужна дополнительная инфа пишите в комментариях

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry всем кого побеспокоил своим вопросом, проблема была достаточно глупая. Когда оборачивал ConstraintLayout через ScrollView я забыл убрать

> android:gravity="center"

такое чувство что ScrollView при появлении клавиатуры не ресайзил экран, а поднимал его на верх. Из-за чего верхушка ConstraintLayout уходила за пределы экрана. Достаточно странное для меня поведение. При условии что манифесте прописано

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Answer (score 1):

Скорее наоборот следует обернуть ScrollView в ConstraintLayout. Но я бы вообще посоветовал использовать `CoordinatorLayout`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/addCoordinatorLayout"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">



        </ScrollView>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Scroll может иметь только одного ребенка, так что внутри него нужен все равно лаяут и возращаемся к проблеме выше.

Comment: CoordinatorLayout я вижу смысл использовать если только я собираюсь выстраивать зависимость при поведении скролов. тут таких зависимостей нет